# How do I export a TypeScript React component which uses Material-UI withStyles?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a React component written in TypeScript which applies the Material-UI style to react-select as shown below.

```js
const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
});

export interface Props<TI> extends WithStyles<typeof styles, true> {
    innerProps: Partial<AsyncSelectProps<TI>>;
    selectRef?: React.RefObject<StateManager<TI>>;
    onSelectionChange?: (selection: TI | undefined) => void;
}

class MaterialReactSelect<TI> extends React.PureComponent<Props<TI>> {
    ...
}

export default withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true})(MaterialReactSelect);
```

How can I modify this so that it's exported as a parameterized type so can be used as

```js
<MaterialReactSelect<string>
    selectRef={this.selectRef}
    onSelectionChange={this.onSelectionChange}
    innerProps={innerProps}
/>
```

rather than

```js
<MaterialReactSelect
    selectRef={this.selectRef}
    onSelectionChange={this.onSelectionChange}
    innerProps={innerProps}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately not an issue with material-ui specifically but higher-order components in general. When using a higher-order component your're losing all generic type information of the wrapped component.

You should be able to observe the same issues with `connect` from `react-redux` or `styled` from `styled-components`.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no solution in the current version of TypeScript?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. At least not with higher-order components. You don't have these issues with using flat components with hooks.

Comment: Do you have an example of using Material-UI as a flat component with hooks for the styles?

Comment: @JonFreedman v4 has a hook variant of withStyles documented in https://next.material-ui.com/styles/basics/#getting-started

Comment: thanks for that - looks like I will just wait for v4 to  be released then